# how to calculate the remaining left time with php and mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, time

i have a situation where i need to calculate the remaining time every 6 hours, whenever i view the time.

i have this setup:

```
<div id="time"><div>
<button>trigger</button>
```

to be more precise i have a trigger that gets the time starter:

```
$(buttom).on('click', function(){
    ..... send through ajax the current time to a php file
    ...if success, get the response and place it in the div
});
```

in the php file i store that time to the database

```
if (isset($_POST['time'])){
    $storeTime->timestore($_POST['time']);
}
```

what happens now is that whenever i view that `div` i should see the left time:

```
<div id="time">5h:50min<div>
```

i vizit again in 30 min i see

```
<div id="time">5h:20min<div>
```

and so on.

the problem is not sending the time back and forth using ajax or something, but sending the correct time.

What i was thinking is to send the time every time i visit the page. First time store it in a table field and the other times to store them in a separate table field

```
id     time1        time2
1      123456..     123124..
```

the `time1` stays unmodified as it is the original time and every time i visit the page i send the new current time and update `time2`

here i get a bit lost.

this is how i get `time1`: `$getTime = $data->getTime($userId);`

and this is the time that comes in every time: `$time`

i also know that 6h is `21600` seconds

so

```
if ( $time >= ($newTime + 21600) ){ 
    //if the current time is bigger than the first time + 6h it means that 6h have passed
    // store the new time in the database for reference as the new main time
} else {
    // 6h have not passed yet and we need to calculate how much time is left
    //here i get confuzed

}
```

I know this post is a bit confuse maybe, but i hope its understandable.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to calculate the remaining amount of time?

Comment: yes please, im not sure why i made it so complicated :)

Comment: let me know below is what you want...

Comment: I think php supports subtraction of dates/times so all you need to do is get the time passed by subtracting `time1` and `time2` then subtract this value from the number of seconds in 6h (21600). This should give you the number of seconds remaining and you can parse it however you want.

Comment: little confused on what you're trying to do, but why don't you just pass the remaining time (or the end time) once on page load and then update it with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to store the time for when you last visited the site you only need to store one time.

So for your example:

```
$current_time          = time();
$last_visit_time       = $data->getTime($userId);
$since_last_visit_time = $current_time - $last_visit_time;
$six_hours_in_seconds  = 21600;

if($since_last_visit_time > $six_hours_in_seconds) {
    // not sure of the function call here so using yours
    // store new time as it's been over 6 hours
    $storeTime->timestore($current_time);
    $remaining_time = $six_hours_in_seconds;
} else {
    $remaining_time = $six_hours_in_seconds - $since_last_visit_time;
}

echo "Remaining Seconds: {$remaining_time}<br />";
```

Part 2 using JavaScript / Ajax you can use this to display the remaning time

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/kLk4f/1/

JS

```
var time_in_seconds = 21600; // this would be the $remaining_time PHP variable

setInterval(function() {
    $('#countdown').html(seconds2time(time_in_seconds));
    time_in_seconds--;
}, 1000);

function seconds2time(seconds) {
    var hours   = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((seconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = seconds - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
    var time = "";

    if (hours != 0) {
      time = hours+":";
    }
    if (minutes != 0 || time !== "") {
      minutes = (minutes < 10 && time !== "") ? "0"+minutes : String(minutes);
      time += minutes+":";
    }
    if (time === "") {
      time = seconds+"s";
    }
    else {
      time += (seconds < 10) ? "0"+seconds : String(seconds);
    }
    return time;
}
```

HTML

```
<span id="countdown"></span>​
```

Comment: that might just be the case, i believe i over think this one, let me try it and if it works ill let you know

Comment: hmmm, the time doesn't seem to change. I insert the time in teh database, and i can see that the time left is 5h:59min, but it stays there.

Comment: You want a constant Count Down?

Comment: no, but i have the time that comes in every time i view that page as  `$time = $_POST['time']`

Comment: i did` $last_visit_time       = $_POST['time']` and now it seems to start form 0 up + the 6 hours

Comment: sry I'm confused could you explain a little more?

Comment: well now i see `6h: 11min` if i check back in 3 min i see `6h: 14min`.. so it's going up

Comment: what is the value of $_POST['time']? when do you call timestore?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7878/discussion-between-patrioticcow-and-phill-pafford)

Answer (score 2):

Use `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(final_time, initial_time))`

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('17:00:00', '09:00:00')) -- 28800

SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('12:30:00', '12:00:00')) -- 1800
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('10:30:00', '10:15:00')) -- 900
```