# Auto Load and Refresh div every 10sec jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile and want to refresh the div in particular time interval.
I tried using

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $("#zabar").load(location.href+" #zabar>*","").fadeIn("slow")
},15000);
```

but what happens that the css styling and struction of that div or button is gone after the auto refresh.
I don't to load the content from other page. Just want to refresh it in particular time.
This is demo here what is happening http://jsfiddle.net/pRTg9/ every thing disappear

Comment: This might help http://jsfiddle.net/kLk4f/1/ Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338824/how-to-calculate-the-remaining-left-time-with-php-and-mysql/9338894#9338894

Comment: @Phill Paffor I'm really sorry jsfiddle is not opening. have to wait little bit.
or pls paste the code on pastebin thanks

Comment: @BasicBridge not just you either. [here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) is a good read for the mean time. fyi, what you are wanting is called "long polling".

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke `.trigger( 'updatelayout' );` on your `div` in your auto_refresh function. Triggering that event should reapply the css styling and struction. It might look something like this:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
$("#zabar").load(location.href+" #zabar>*","").fadeIn("slow");
$("#zabar").trigger('updatelayout');
},15000);
```

The `updatelayout` event is described at the bottom of [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html) in the jQuery Mobile  Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch your new list content by Ajax, then replace it into the list and call "listview('refresh')" on your list.
See http://jsfiddle.net/RRCAK/20/